# Get the const Id of iPhone device like UDID

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

When my app run and it's will send an Id to the web service, then the web service will save this value(Id), if I delete my app on my iPhone then build again, I need get this Id again to send to the web service. Because the web service need to know if this is the iPhone had register which had an id saved into the database or it's new. As far as I know, I can use the UDID, but if I do that then apple will reject my app. If have any value is a const in iPhone like the UDID? If not, please recommend for me the way to solved my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it important for your app to know whether or not a specific device has registered?  Devices are sold second-hand, you know?  Wouldn't the Apple ID be more valuable to track?

Comment: This sort of thing isn't allowed by Apple any more. And no you can't use the UDID because Apple have done more then deprecated it they have removed it so there is no way to get it anymore.

Comment: See the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505015/is-mac-address-of-iphone-unique-and-will-it-change